# inheritance and equals method

Tags: java, oop

I have the following code, the question is what `equals` function will be called?
The answer is - the `equals` of an Object class, can someone explain why?
I thought that the `equals` of A class will be called since in runtime a is A and A has a proper `equals` function for class A as b is a reference of class A.
Why my assumption is wrong?

```
public class MainClass
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Object a = new A();
    A b = new B();

    System.out.println(a.equals(b));

  }
}


public class A
{
    public boolean equals (A other)
    {
      System.out.println("a");
      return true;
    }
}

public class B extends A
{

    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
      System.out.println("b");
      return true;
    }

    public boolean equals (B other)
    {
      System.out.println("c");
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: only `.equals(Object o)` is visible through the `Object`-reference  `a`.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi That would end up in a compiler error. It is not an override, as the argument type is `A` , not Object. That is the whole point: A is **not** overriding Object.equals(). So I think you need to pay more attention when providing hints to other users.

Comment: @GhostCat you're right thanks

Comment: *The answer is - the equals of an Object class, can someone explain why?*, can you explain *Why it should be anything else?* that will answer your question for you.